# How to change mode of image from RGB to Grayscale and reshape using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

I want to change the mode to grayscale and reshape the image to 28x28 pixels.

So far I have done this.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('image2.jpg')
print(img.format, img.size, img.mode)
ndarray = np.array(img)
```

**[Image]**

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use numpy? You're loading it with ``PIL``, which has good functions for converting to grayscale and scaling. You can load the resulting image in a numpy array after the proprocessing.

Comment: I used the `img.convert('L')` to convert to grayscale. For scaling, I tried `img.resize(28,28)` but that didn't work.

Comment: From the docs: ``Image.resize(size, resample=0, box=None)`` size – The requested size in pixels, as a 2-tuple: (width, height).. So try ``img.resize((28,28))`` and you should be fine.